# Touchpad not working in Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad

I recently moved to Linux Mint 20 from windows 10. Everything except touchpad is working fine.

> System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v:
> 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.6
> wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal  Machine:   Type: Laptop System: FUJITSU product:
> LIFEBOOK A514 v: N/A serial:  Chassis:
> type: 10 serial: 
> Mobo: FUJITSU model: FJNBB3A serial:  UEFI [Legacy]: FUJITSU // Phoenix
> v: Version 2.07 date: 07/03/2015

These are the things i have tried till now.

```
 xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera: FJ Camera                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I couldn't find any setting related to touchpad in BIOS.
The enable touch pad is ON in System Settings.

Tried installing below packages

```
xserver-xorg-input-libinput 
xserver-xorg-input-evdev 
xserver-xorg-input-mouse
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

I tried live boot of Ubuntu also, which too have the same issue.

Comment: Why was it down voted? I have shown the effort I have taken. I believe I have provided enough details.

Comment: I just got the same problem today. Then I did `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` and reboot. Everything start to work!

Comment: I tried upgrade. No more packages to update. But still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer from mint forum.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=326181&p=1855207#p1855207

I added the following parameters to kernel parameters and now touchpad is working.

```
i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux
```